# Optimization for compilation process of Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to optimize compilation process of Angular Directives in case of a complex DOM structure where more than one directive need to be compiled for a single UI component.

```html
<chat-window>
 <chat-action-bar></chat-action-bar>
 <message-list></message-list>
 <text-editor></text-editor>
</chat-window>
```

Above is the DOM structure of a single chat window.

I need some suggestions from experienced Angular JS developers how to improve the compilation of this complex Angular directives to improve the load/render time of its appearance in html page.

For your understanding, i have already optimized my directives watches in a template file of a directive but still issue exists.

Comment: Can you provide the code to everything that these directives depend on and that of the directives themselves?

Comment: @papakia can not share the code atm cos of some restrictions hope you will understand this, but can you please suggest some of your views to solve this problem.

Comment: It is hard to provide any real enhancements without a benchmark of different aspects of your code. There are a few basic tips here to optimise performance: http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/

Comment: If you are struggling with appearance on loading then i suggest maybe making use of the [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive and/or perhaps showing a loader when the elements/data are loading to inform the user that something is happening

Comment: @papakia Actually here load/render is in context of that particular UI component which is chat window, not in context of whole page first load time.

Comment: It really depends, We can't really guess what performance issue you might be facing, it depends case by case when it comes to angular. Better share code what each directive is doing & what exact problem you're facing..